# How to escape only message instead of all row in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, escaping, pattern-layout

I have the following PatternLayout:

```
public class EscapedEnhancedPatternLayout extends EnhancedPatternLayout {
    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(super.format(event));
    }
}
```

but this escapes full logging row.

I want to have something like this but only for message.

but `LoggingEvent` class has not `setMessage` and `setRenderedMessage` methods.

And I don't see copy constructor at `LoggingEvent`. If `LoggingEvent` had copy constructor I can inherited from `LoggingEvent` and override methods mentioned below.

Please advise me how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no `LoggingEvent(LoggingEvent other)` constructor, but you can pass the event's values to the [LoggingEvent constructor](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html#LoggingEvent(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.Category,%20long,%20org.apache.log4j.Level,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo,%20java.util.Map)) in your `format` method like this:

```
@Override
public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
    Object msgObj = event.getMessage();

    LoggingEvent newEvent = new LoggingEvent(
        event.getFQNOfLoggerClass(),
        event.getLogger(), event.getTimeStamp(),
        event.getLevel(),
        StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(msgObj != null ? msgObj.toString() : null),
        event.getThreadName(),
        event.getThrowableInformation(),
        event.getNDC(),
        event.getLocationInformation(),
        event.getProperties());

    return super.format(newEvent);
}
```

This will create a new `LoggingEvent` from the old one with all values set. The `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` method can now modify the the `message` without affecting the other properties and you can still use `super.format`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to create a customized `LogEventFactory`. A `LogEventFactory` is used to generate LogEvents. Applications may replace the standard `LogEventFactory` by setting the value of the system property `Log4jLogEventFactory` to the name of the custom LogEventFactory class.

The method that will be called to create a instance of `LogEvent` is as follows:

```
LogEvent createEvent(String loggerName,
               org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker marker,
               String fqcn,
               org.apache.logging.log4j.Level level,
               org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message data,
               List<Property> properties,
               Throwable t)
```

and `DefaultLogEventFactory` is the basic implementation for log4j. In your case you could extend the basic implementation and escape the message after which you call the default implementation. It would become something like this:

```
public class MyCustomLogEventFactory extends DefaultLogEventFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a log event.
     *
     * @param loggerName The name of the Logger.
     * @param marker An optional Marker.
     * @param fqcn The fully qualified class name of the caller.
     * @param level The event Level.
     * @param data The Message.
     * @param properties Properties to be added to the log event.
     * @param t An optional Throwable.
     * @return The LogEvent.
     */
     @Override
    public LogEvent createEvent(final String loggerName, final Marker marker,
                             final String fqcn, final Level level, final Message data,
                             final List<Property> properties, final Throwable t) {
        super.createEvent(loggerName, marker, fqcn, level, StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(data != null ? data.toString() : null), properties, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see DefaultLogEventFactory

Comment: It's in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl` version 2.x of log4j

Comment: I use 1.2.17 version

Comment: Are you able to upgrade and/or log4j bridge?

Comment: Ok, instead of this you could also extend the log4J `Logger` and override the methods `getLogger` and   `forcedLog`. An alternative might be to use aspectj and intercept the call to `forcedLog` and make the change to the message in the interceptor.